# How to have in Ubuntu, Windows like RDP server and client?

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, remote-desktop, vnc, rdp

Connecting remotely from OSX to Windows or Windows to Windows using RDP protocol is 90% time faster then using x11vnc in Ubuntu.

Is there any commercial or free remote desktop for Ubuntu which works faster then VNC or RDP and very stable?

(i need to have visual remote desktop for making a security/emergency monitoring wall project, where quality,stability,speed matters)

(project scenario: security guys have a dual screen where its real-time 24/7 connected to remote location Ubuntu Desktop such as 200 desktops. Live preview and live instant access with mouse, keyboard on the fly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On Ubuntu 14.04** - SERVER

`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession`

**On Ubuntu 14.04** - CLIENT

`sudo apt-get install x2goclient`